# How can I change my sign-in account through Yahoo to Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, status-norepro, login, android-app

I have installed the new Stack Exchange app on my android. Since I log into my SE accounts with my Yahoo OpenID on the desktop site, I tried logging into the SE app through Yahoo but it gives a security warning & doesn't allow me to log into SE.

Can I transfer my existing account from using Yahoo to the Stack Exchange OpenID? I obviously don't want to start fresh with a totally new account.

Comment: Questions about using StackOverflow or the way it operates should be posted on [meta]

Comment: @MikeW can u please migrate it to Meta SE.SO than.

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this (just went and made a new account with Yahoo credentials and logged into the android app), what do you mean by "a security warning"?

Can you [grab a screenshot](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1773)?

As a work around, you can [add an arbitrary number of credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) to your existing account on the web.  If you're Android phone is connected to your Google account, that's probably the easiest one.

On the login screen you can see which Google (or Facebook, if you use that) account we'd use to log you into Stack Exchange before you click it.

[image]

Comment: When i tried to log in, yahoo redirected me to a page saying some unusual activity has been detected & i must change my a/c password asap. Tried this 3 times. Same message. But the resent update to SE app(y'day) seems to have resolved the issue. Anyway i tried to add another log in credentials, this time through SE a/c(new) & link it to my old a/c. Problem resolved. Thanks to u & that comment below the question